# Will Core Data create the persistent store file for me?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Please tell me: If I use Core Data in my iPhone app, I have basically two files. The mydatamodel.xcdatamodel file, and then I need an .sqlite file. Apple provides this code snippet:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSString *appDirPath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *storeFileName = @"mystore.sqlite";
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[appDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:storeFileName]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Will this create the file if it's not available already?

```
[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]
```

My app doesn't need initial data, because it will download it when the user launches the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Core Data will create the SQLite db just after the first launch of your application in your app delegate.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. What if I provided that file already? Afaik I can't ship it directly into the documents dir. So I would first copy it there before attempting to create it, right?

Comment: Correct. You would have a release version in your app bundle and copy it over.

Comment: If i did the tutorial for iOS on the developer website, and my app crashes saying there is no persistent store available. How could i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The boiler-plate Core Data stack code provided by Apple's templates will create the database file if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: If i did the tutorial for iOS on the developer website, and my app crashes saying there is no persistent store available. How could i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that method adds a new persistent store of a specified type at a given location, and returns the new store.  [Here is the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:).

Comment: If i did the tutorial for iOS on the developer website, and my app crashes saying there is no persistent store available. How could i fix this?